# Keep socket running in the background in hybrid application (Angular and Apache Cordova)

Tags: android, angular, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid angular application and Apache Cordova, in it I have a chat, I want the chat socket to continue running even when the application is paused or completely closed.
Any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using any cloud Messaging service such as [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) 
or [one-signal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/product-overview)

Check the links to know more about these services and how it works.

That is if you talking about just receiving messages in a chat app. 
but if you need your app to do some functionality in the Background you can use one of the npm cordova plugins like this plugin [cordova-plugin-background-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-service)

To perform some functionality in the background while your app is not running.

Comment: I have a chat service that uses sockets to work, I am trying to make the socket connection continue running in the background, even if the application was completely closed

Comment: as I told you if you want to add any logic to work in the background while your app is not running you have to  add it in a background-service that means that you need to add some code to handle socket connections and handler of receiving messages in a background service